# ISP speed slowed down by the Router

Tags: wireless-router

I realized that when I connect my laptop directly to my ISP modem I get close to the 60 Mbps speed that they advertise.  But when I connect my laptop directly to my wifi router through a cable or wirelessly I only get around 25 Mbps speed.  Do you think I need to change my router?  The router I have is Sitecom WL-611 300N  with the following specs
Maximum Wireless Speed: 300 Mbps
WiFi standards supported:
 802.11b (11 Mbps)
802.11g (54 Mbps)
802.11n (draft 2.0)

Do you think I can get close to 60 Mbps with my current router or I have to change completely.  Thanks regards

Comment: Clearly you won't be able to get 60Mbps on a wireless connection.  Furthermore its very likely the modem has 10/100/1000 ports and your router only has 10/100 based on the age of it.  The fact it has slower ports would explain the speed difference.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, there is a drop in speed from modem to router, even on ethernet. The router you have does support 10/100 ethernet ports, but 60Mbps should not be a problem over 10/100 ethernet. I would recommend upgrading to a Gigabit router or at least borrowing and testing speeds with a gigabit router. It should solve the speed issue and give you some nice file transfer speeds over ethernet.